# No keyframes visible in action editor

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I had finished animating an action and was previewing it. I accidentally hit <kbd>R</kbd> while the animation was playing and not wanting the rotation, I hit escape (and probably a couple of other characters because fat fingers).
Now I don't have anything at all listed in the dope sheet summary. Also there are no keyframe nodes in the action editor. I can still see the animations being done if I scrub the timeline, there's just nothing in the graph editor.
I've tried to figure out how to fix it, but I cannot seem to find it.

Comment: please post screenshot

Comment: It sounds like you may of simply unselect the object with the animation.

Comment: have you clicked the " show errors only" icon ( one next to the ghost )

Comment: yes! The "show errors only" icon was indeed it! I clicked it and things came back as they were earlier. Thanks!
edit: Chebhou, I'd mark yours as the answer if I could figure out how (all sorts of fail on my part today it seems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chebhou's response was correct. Make sure "Show Errors Only" was accidentally clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case everything disappeared because I added some characters by mistake to the "search" space, next to the "show errors only".

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Please add details to your question so others can also use your solution

Comment: Hello, welcome to BSE, since this is not an answer that you are providing to the question, please use the comment instead.